# Tools/Framework to make html slides (similar to /better than keynote)?

Tags: css, html, frameworks, slideshow

I have been seeing a lot of [html slides](http://backbone-dot-js-intro.heroku.com/#shall-not-around) these days. They falls into similar pattern. (use arrow keys for navigation, similar transition effects)

So I wanna to know is there tools/frameworks to make those slides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js)

You can see it in action with [this](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored) nice demo.

Comment: Dude, it is rather cool!

Answer (score 2):

I like these solutions:

- [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/) by [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com).
- [Shower](http://pepelsbey.github.com/shower/en.htm) by [Vadim Makeev](http://pepelsbey.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be the most popular: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide

Answer (score 0):

There is a good comparitive list of html slides in http://www.impressivewebs.com/html-slidedeck-toolkits.